# Cannot re-initialize after first initialize value to integer array

Tags: c

I first initialize 0 to counter[10], and it is OK. However, somewhere I want to re-initialize with 0 again but fail.

The error message is

`[Warning] extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {

  int digit, counter[10] = {0}; //Declare variable "digit" to store individual number to be compared and declare an array for the input numbers
  bool rep_digits; //Declare a boolean variable to determine whether the input numbers has repetitive numbers or none
  int n; //Declare variable "n" to store the input numbers

  while (true) { //This while loop serves as a loop for the user input
    
    printf("\nEnter a number (capped at  on this compiler): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n == 0) { //The user input loop terminates when the user input a 0
    break;
    }
    
    printf("Repeated digits(s): \n");

    while (n > 0) { //If the condition is true, execute the arguments inside
        digit = n % 10; //Obtain the remainder of the input number
        counter[digit]++; //Increase the counter for the obtained remainder in the array
        if (counter[digit] == 2) { //If the counter of that particular remainder is equal (and only equal) to 2, print out the number
            printf("%2d\n", digit); 
            rep_digits = true;  //Set the boolean variable to true if there is a repetitive number in the input
        }
        n /= 10; //Divide the input number by 10 to determine the next number either repetitive or not
    }
        
    counter[10] = {0}; // re-initialize to 0
        
    if (rep_digits == false) { //If the boolean variable stays false then display this message
        printf("No repeated digits\n");
    } 
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't do that. If you want to set all the values to 0 you could use a loop, or you could use memset to set all the bytes to 0. You could also move the declaration with the initialization inside the while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`counter[10] = {0};` writing beyond the array size causes undefined behavior.

suppose you have array size as `int counter[10]`, you should write only from `counter[0]` till `counter[9]`

if you want to initialize all the array elements to `0`, then you can do it two ways.

1. `int counter[10] = {0}; \\this works only at the same place where you declare`
2. `memset(counter,0,sizeof(counter)); \\ this can be done at any other place in the program`

In your program replace `counter[10] = {0};` with `memset(counter,0,sizeof(counter));`

it should work just fine.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, thanks dint have a proper look at the program before, updated the answer properly by giving explanation

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was looking for an alternative way to re-initialize my array elements to 0 without it going through declaration again. You also pointed out my dumb mistake that after declaration, the array "counter[10] = {0}" where 10 is actually the index not the size of the array anymore.

Comment: @BrandonJ, up voting is the only way of saying thank you here :)

Comment: I tried to vote ur answer and verify it, but I am still new to stackoverflow, it says I need more reputation

Comment: I think below the down vote option there is an option to accept as answer you can click on that

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `int counter[10] = {0}`

Use memset
`int counter[10]; memset(counter,0,sizeof(counter));`

The above memset line fills every value of counter array to 0.

Comment: Worth noting that `memset` works on bytes, not ints, so replace that `0` with a `1` and the result will not be an array of values set to 1.